# Codeigniter editing uri segment for pagination purposes

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a url `http://localhost/basic/Logiciel/ab/current_page/10/date_from/1571691600000/date_to/1572382800000/time_from/30/time_to/60`

and i am getting the current url and the next page like:

```
$cu = current_url();
$current_page = $this->input->get('current_page'); 
$next_page = (int)$current_page + 1;
```

I want to edit `$current_page` and set it to a variable of my choosing. Is there a function in the uri or input class that can allow me to change a uri segment to form a new url or must i parse_url and break my url into an array the way i would if was not using codeigniter?.

```
$parse_cu = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($parse_cu, $cu_arr);
$cu_arr['current_page'];
```

Comment: how about using segment(), see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html#class-reference?

Comment: You mean `$this->uri->segment(3, $var);`

Comment: $var would be returned, if segment 3 is not found, so maybe not what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the [CI URI class](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html#class-reference) you can use:

getter:

```
$arr=($this->uri->uri_to_assoc());
```

which outputs

```
Array
(
    [current_page] => 10
    [date_from] => 1571691600000
    [date_to] => 1572382800000
    [time_from] => 30
    [time_to] => 60
)
```

so fetch 'current_page':

```
    $arr=$this->uri->uri_to_assoc();
    $cp=$arr['current_page'];
```

and build the new uri string:

```
    $arr1=$arr;
    $arr1['current_page']=$cp+1;
    echo $this->uri->assoc_to_uri($arr1);
```

(where +1 could stand for any +$var), which outputs:

```
current_page/11/date_from/1571691600000/date_to/1572382800000/time_from/30/time_to/60
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to use here is CodeIgniter's URI class.

The URI class has a couple of methods like `segment()`, `uri_to_assoc()` and `assoc_to_uri` that will let you do exactly what you are looking for.

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: Turning the url to an array is the easy part. How can i produce the url with the variable set:?

Comment: You see how you have this method called `assoc_to_uri()`. You use that one where you update the uri parts in an associative array, and you generate the final uri with that method.